# All contours are not getting converted to shapefile in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis

I am reading data from a csv file and plotting contours using python. The code works but when I check shapefile created, I can see only few contour lines are getting plotted whereas when I check image plot there are many more lines. What is going wrong in this code? I think the cs.collections is creating some problem but I am not able to figure it out.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from shapely.geometry import mapping, Polygon, LineString,MultiLineString
import fiona

# set up plot
plt.clf()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='w', frame_on=False)


# grab data
data = pd.read_csv('Filename.csv', sep=',')
norm = Normalize()

# define map extent
lllon = -180
lllat = -90
urlon = 180
urlat = 90

# Set up Basemap instance
m = Basemap(#projection = 'merc',llcrnrlon = lllon, llcrnrlat = lllat, urcrnrlon = urlon, urcrnrlat = urlat,resolution='h', epsg=4326)
# transform lon / lat coordinates to map projection
data['projected_lon'], data['projected_lat'] = m(*(data.CLON.values, data.CLAT.values))
# grid data
numcols, numrows = 100, 100
xi = np.linspace(data['projected_lon'].min(), data['projected_lon'].max(), numcols)
yi = np.linspace(data['projected_lat'].min(), data['projected_lat'].max(), numrows)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

# interpolate
x, y, z = data['projected_lon'].values, data['projected_lat'].values, data.PRES.values
zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)


# contour plot
cs = plt.contour(xi, yi, zi,zorder=4)
plt.show()

lenvar = (len(cs.collections))   #number of contours
print(lenvar)
#print(cs.collections)

lines = []  # Empty list for contour sections

for i in range(lenvar):
  n = i
  p = cs.collections[i].get_paths()[0]
  v = p.vertices # getting the individual verticies as a numpy.ndarray
  x = v[:,0] #takes first column
  y = v[:,1] #takes second column
  line = LineString([(i[0], i[1]) for i in zip(x,y)])  #Defines Linestring
  lines.append(line) #appends to list

schema = {'geometry': 'LineString','properties': {'id': 'int'}}  # sets up parameter for shapefile

with fiona.open('ConShp.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as c:  # creates new file to be written to
  for j in range(len(lines)):
     l = (lines[j])   # creates variable
     print(l)
     print(type(l))
     c.write({'geometry': mapping(l),'properties': {'id': j},})
```

data Sample is like:
Lat, Lon, Value
18.73, 26.34, 5000
20.00, 60.00, 7000

[Shapefile_plot_in_GIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liv2u.png)
[Image of Plot in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0uER.jpg)

Comment: Unfortunately it's unclear what you are asking. Since the code itself is not runnable because of missing data, people are unable reproduce the issue and thus to understand the problem.

Comment: I am trying to create isoline plot for a parameter. Inputs are Lat, Lon and Value. They are read from csv file. When I plot the contours using matplotlib, the code works fine and generates desired output. In addition I want to generate shapefile of this contours instead of image plot. When i tried to generate a shapefile only few of the contour lines are getting written to shapefile.